# I'm having trouble installing and running a program on Google Collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, vnc, carla

Update : all what I need know how to use cloudflared?

I followed this:

> https://colab.research.google.com/github/MichaelBosello/carla-colab/blob/master/carla-simulator.ipynb

In order to install carla simulation on google colab

first: I don't know what the programs are in the requirments field. Do I really need to install them on my pc or not?
[requirement field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYPwy.png)

second : After running all cells :

This message appeared to me : [error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u37Mx.png) and carla simulator does not open!

third : all files appears in directory of colab after installed them but when I try to run a file it prints that : [no module found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xVJC.png)

I want to understand a little bit about vnc and do I really need it here?how?
how to solve problems I showed above?

or If you can make this notebook work as it is I will be very thankful to you

Comment: Did you install cloundflared and TurboVNC on your PC? you have to install them on your PC, CARLA will run on notebook but for visualization and working with carla you need to install those on your PC. VNC is a remote access software. You actually can see screen or visualization of a remote PC on your PC. similar to screen share feature in other software but with control.

Comment: I installed them but I does not any idea about how can I link them

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: update: I understood everything except how to operate cloudflared